# Windows 8.1 upgrade results in Green Screen of Death fixed only by changing user

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update, windows-8.1-upgrade

after accepting Windows 8 proposal to upgrade to 8.1, and after restarting, my system behaves as follows

1. It logins normally
2. Seconds after login a green screen with "please wait" written on it appears.
3. The mouse button is also in " please wait" mode.
4. I can use Alt+tab to make things switch in the background, but I can't escape this screen.

Waiting for hours doesn't help, nor does a hard restart. What can I do?

- Edit

What did help is the Method 3 in  [this link](http://www.optimizewindows8.net/2014/01/fixing-please-wait-screen-problem-in-windows-8-8-1/). **problem now** is that it demands me to work from a new user, while a lot of my old stuff is under my old user (for example, Matlab). How can I go back and fix my old user?

just to remark that methods 1,2 and 5 **didn't** prove themselves useful.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might need to re-install 8.1 I have seen this before, its normally due to a bad install. only way to explain it.

Comment: How can I re install?

Comment: What type of hardware is this? Is this a tablet or is this just a laptop or desktop?

Comment: I'm using a laptop

Comment: problem fixed only through changing my user, see the body for the new edit