# One User is Stuck, the Other Doesn't Work

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

recently I had a [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/838956/windows-8-1-upgrade-results-in-green-screen-of-death-fixed-only-by-changing-user?noredirect=1#comment1104751_838956) Which was resolved by method 3 in [this great article](http://www.optimizewindows8.net/2014/01/fixing-please-wait-screen-problem-in-windows-8-8-1/). Without going into the whole thing, the problem is as follows:

My old user is stuck in green-screen-of-please-wait-death, and I need to restore my ability to use it from the new user.

Any Ideas

Comment: Using a new user with Administrator permissions take ownership of the User's profile directory.  Change the name of the user's profile directory.  Once you do this try logging into the profile in question.  If the profile works take ownership of the renamed folder and transfer the folders one by one.

Comment: How is this any different than your original (since-updated) question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 upgrade results in Green Screen of Death fixed only by changing user](http://superuser.com/questions/838956/windows-8-1-upgrade-results-in-green-screen-of-death-fixed-only-by-changing-user)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I was in a dilemma about that, since the original purpose of the question is quite different, and the fact that I have updated it just changes it completely. For all practical purposes, I resolved myself the first question and now have a totally new one, at least from the perspective of future users...

Comment: @Ramhound Where is that's user profile directory?

Comment: You are kidding right?  **` C:\Users\ `**

Comment: Ok. This I know of, but you think renaming it will solve the problem for the old user? Why?